# Showing Probability/Expected Value Relation

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable which takes values $0,1,2,3...n$ and satisfies $E[X]=Var[X]=1$ then show that $P(X>k) \leq 1/k^2$ for every $k$.

I started with $E[X]=Var[X]=1$

I know that , $E[X]=\sum_{k=0}^n P(X>k)$ and $E[X^2]+E[X]= 2 \sum_{k=0}^n kP(X>k)$. I couldn't able to make use them here. Is there any way around to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

We use [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality#Chebyshev.27s_inequality). That is, $$P(|X-E[X]| \ge a) \le \frac{Var[X]}{a^2}.$$

We have,
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(|X - 1|\ge k) & \le & \frac{1}{k^2}\\
\text{or, } P( X \ge k+1\text{ or } X\le 1-k) & \le & \frac{1}{k^2}\\
\text{or, } P(X \ge k+1) &\le & \frac{1}{k^2}\\
\text{or, } P(X>k) &\le& \frac{1}{k^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$